# Runtime.getRuntime() restart mac Java IM

Tags: java, macos, runtime-error, runtime.exec

My os is MAC OS 10.11.3.

I using Spark as our IM（Instant messaging），but when the IM log out，IM give an error，said：

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "open": error=2, No such file or directory .

But when Eclipse runs it， it worked well，and when I wrapped it a mac package and installed it and run it, click "log out" button, it throws errors.

In program, when I log out，I launch a new IM，meanwhile，I killed the old IM application.

Furthermore，in terminal，no matter what I run how many times `“open -a Spark”`，it just open the same IM，

The source as follows：

```
public boolean restartApplicationWithScript() {
    String command = null;
    try {
        if (Spark.isMac()) {
            command = "open -a " + Default.getString(Default.SHORT_NAME);
        }

        String commands[] = {"open", "/Applications/Spark.app"}; 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);

        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.error("Error trying to restart application with script", e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of variable `command`? You never use it for anything.

Comment: Dear Andreas,thank you , yes, it just i test the open command , but it doesn't work , and do you have some suggest ？

Answer (score 0):

The exception seems to be saying that it cannot find the `open` command.  That seems a bit odd, since it is a standard MacOS command.  So I suspect that the reason that it cannot be found is that it is not on the `PATH`.

- Try giving the absolute pathname for the `open` command.  Running `which open` should tell you what it is.
- If `open` is a shell builtin on MacOS, then you will need to create a subshell to run the command.

Comment: Dear Stephen C, thans a lots, i attempted to use the absolute path name ，but does not work，and  how i create a subshell to run the command,

Comment: Before you do that, have you *checked* whether `open` is a shell built-in.  If you haven't checked, then you are probably wasting your time running the command in a subshell.

Comment: Dear Stephen C,thanks for your reply, i checked the open is not a shell built-in,used "type open" in shell , and it give me a "open is hashed (/usr/bin/open)" , so i think  it not a built-in command , since i "type cd"  responded a "cd is a shell builtin" , so , how can i do next, im most grateful for your help

Comment: i used "enable open" in terminal，it responseed "-bash: enable: open: not a shell builtin",i ensure it not a built-in command,thank you

Comment: In that case I'm stumped.  (And I don't have a Mac to run your code.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all， i solved it by 2 step ：
1， cmdline = { "open", "-na", "Microsoft Excel" };  this add a "n" ,otherwise，it will open the same app 。 
2，chmod -R 777 youAppPath，if not do this ，the app can't issue the command